# can't solve deprecation warnings

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

Every time I install a new package or when I run `npm audit fix (--force)`, I get deprecation warnings which are not getting fixed. I deleted package lock and tried everything but nothing works. Seems also to be a global error since it doesn't matter in which of my projects I do that. I try updating vue-cli which worked.

Does somebody have a solution to that?

Here are the warnings:

```
 @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
```

Comment: You say it happens in all of your projects. If you create an empty directory, change into it, and run `npm install vue`, do you still get these messages? If not, then please post the `package.json` of one of your projects with the problem, as it is related to a package there. If you do get the messages in a blank directory, they're probably tied to a globally installed package, so please post the output of `npm list -g --depth=0`.

Comment: @kdau I still get the warnings. I did npm list and this came up:                                
       test@ D:\Benutzer\User\Downloads\projects\test
└── vue@2.6.14

Comment: Hmm, that still looks like the list for a specific project. The `-g` flag is important; it has to be `npm list -g --depth=0` exactly. When you do get that list, please go ahead and add it to your question for legibility.

Comment: @kdau Sorry, I'm dumb... didn't copy the whole command. After running it now, it looks like this: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── @vue/cli@4.5.13

Comment: Thanks. I don't use Vue CLI myself, but I installed it and got most of the same warnings you did. Looks like they're known issues that will be fixed in the upcoming @vue/cli v5. I'm not going to call this an answer, but there you go.